# Firebase function works as expected using 'Firebase Serve' but throws ERROR 400 when deployed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to use firebase as a proxy to pull data from an API to a react application to avoid CORS restrictions. I can access the data with the code below when using Firebase Serve but throws a 400 when deployed? Appreciate any guideance.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const axios = require('axios');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
admin.initializeApp();


// @Route: /orders
// @Desc: Get Orders from cartrover API using Firebase as a proxy to enable CORS

app.get('/orders', (req, res) => {
    const user = req.body.username;
    const pass = req.body.password;
    
    cors(req, res, () => {
        axios
            .get('https://api.cartrover.com/v1/merchant/orders/list/shipped', {
                auth: {
                    username: user,
                    password: pass,
                },
            })

            .then((resp) => {
                res.send(resp.data);
            });
    });
});

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

When testing on localhost with 'Firebase Serve' I get a JSON object as a response from the API as expected. When I deploy the firebase function and make the same request I get the following error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
<title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title>
<style>
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0
    }

    html,
    code {
        font: 15px/22px arial, sans-serif
    }

    html {
        background: #fff;
        color: #222;
        padding: 15px
    }

    body {
        margin: 7% auto 0;
        max-width: 390px;
        min-height: 180px;
        padding: 30px 0 15px
    }

    *>body {
        background: url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;
        padding-right: 205px
    }

    p {
        margin: 11px 0 22px;
        overflow: hidden
    }

    ins {
        color: #777;
        text-decoration: none
    }

    a img {
        border: 0
    }

    @media screen and (max-width:772px) {
        body {
            background: none;
            margin-top: 0;
            max-width: none;
            padding-right: 0
        }
    }

    #logo {
        background: url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;
        margin-left: -5px
    }

    @media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi) {
        #logo {
            background: url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;
            -moz-border-image: url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0
        }
    }

    @media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2) {
        #logo {
            background: url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;
            -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%
        }
    }

    #logo {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 54px;
        width: 150px
    }
</style>
<a href=//www.google.com/> <span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
<p><b>400.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
    <p>Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "throws a 400"?  Please edit the question to be clear about what you're doing that causes an error, along with the specific error message.  The question should contain enough information that anyone can use the reproduce the problem.  I also suggest reading about how to create a [complete minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: updates with the error

Comment: Please edit the question to include the steps you take to cause the problem.  It's not enough to say "when I make the same request".  You should detail exactly what you're doing so that we could do the same.  The output HTML is not terribly helpful here - code and procedure would be more helpful.